# Rails sitemap generator show wrong index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap, sitemap-generator-gem

Having a hard time with sitemap_generator.

Finally made it work but now it shows the wrong index of the vacancy pages that I created.

It should include all the vacancies currently online: e.g.
http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com/**vacancies/179**

But if you take a look what it actually includes in the sitemap file:

http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com/sitemap.xml.gz

It shows vacancies that do not exist (the index is too high):
e.g. it shows the vacancy:
http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com/vacancies/**641**

Here is my sitemap.rb file:

```
# Set the host name for URL creation
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  Vacancy.find_each do |vacancy|
    add vacancy_path(vacancy), :lastmod => vacancy.updated_at, :priority => 0.5
  end
end
```

I hope someone can take a look at it and tell me what I miss. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you run the sitemap generator? Do you run it in the correct environment on the server?

Comment: rake sitemap:refresh

Comment: I also did "heroku run rake sitemap:refresh" to run it on the server. Both has the same mistake. Does this answer your question? I am very unexperienced with sitemap